# Getting data out of knockout js components

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have seen many examples across the internet about how to display data with knockout js components. The params feature makes it easy to pass anything in to display. But nowhere have I seen how you can get data out of a component.

How does one data-bind something on a component?

Example:

What if I wanted a component that automatically serialized a form input.

```
ko.components.register('form-serializer', {
    viewModel: function(params){
        this.value = ko.observable();
        this.name = params.name

        this.serialize = function(){
            return this.name + '=' + this.value();
        }
    },
    template: '<input data-bind="textInput: value"/>'
}
```

How would I call serialize from my view model?

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of what you mean by getting data out of a component? You could pass in an observable in params which could belong to the "outside".

Comment: I have updated the question to add an example

Comment: Where should the serialization end up? You could still just pass in an observable with params that you write the serialization to instead of returning it somewhere.

Comment: To me that feels much more messy than calling the method directly, but i could just have my methodologies of ko components incorrect. Is that how you would get data out of a component?

Comment: Could you make an example of how you wished this would work so that I can understand where you are coming from? That is, show how you would like to consume the serialize method.

Comment: Well, I tried to think of an example but couldn't. I guess I need to think more about application rather than conceptualization. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Passing an object (usually an observable, but not necessarily) as a parameter to a component allows both the component and the parent to read and write it, so it's not one direction. You're not just passing data in (or out). You're sharing resources.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ko.dataFor](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) inorder to get the viewmodel that is bound to that component and then just call the member functions or variables from it. But for some particular reasons I am not a fan of using this because it gives me the hint that something is wrong with my structure.

Another way which I prefer is putting the viewmodel of the component to another variable so that you can just access it.

Like:

```
var formSerializer = function(params){
    this.value = ko.observable();
    this.name = params.name

    this.serialize = function(){
        return this.name + '=' + this.value();
    }
};

var serializer;
ko.components.register("form-serializer", {
    template: '<input data-bind="textInput: value"/>',
    viewModel: {
        createViewModel: function(params){
            serializer = new formSerializer(params);
            return serializer;
        }
    }
});
```

Thus you can just call the `serialize` function via `serializer.serialize()`.